# LINQ Intersect based on Property

Tags: c#, linq, join, intersect

I'm trying to find an intersect on two collection where the items overlap having an inverse state.

```
public class Sample
{
    public int SampleNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    public bool SampleState { get; set; }
}
```

Example:

```
List<Sample> ListOfSamples1 = new List<Sample>();
List<Sample> ListOfSamples2 = new List<Sample>();

ListOfSamples1.Add( new Sample() {SampleNumber=1, StartTime = new DateTime(2018, 12, 1, 0, 0, 0), EndTime = new DateTime(2018, 12, 1, 0, 10, 0), SampleState= true });
ListOfSamples1.Add( new Sample() {SampleNumber=2, StartTime = new DateTime(2018, 12, 1, 0, 20, 0), EndTime = new DateTime(2018, 12, 1, 0, 30, 0), SampleState= false });

ListOfSamples2.Add( new Sample() {SampleNumber=3, StartTime = new DateTime(2018, 12, 1, 0, 5, 0), EndTime = new DateTime(2018, 12, 1, 0, 7, 0), SampleState= false});
ListOfSamples2.Add( new Sample() {SampleNumber=4, StartTime = new DateTime(2018, 12, 1, 0, 21, 0), EndTime = new DateTime(2018, 12, 1, 0, 22, 0), SampleState= true});
```

I would like to return samples from `ListOfSamples2` that intersect with the samples that exist in `ListOfSamples1` where the `SampleState` is opposite.

For instance `ListOfSamples2[0]` has a `StartTime` and `EndTime` that does reside in `ListOfSamples1[0]` and their states are opposite.

I am doing this with a `ForEach` but am looking for a more elegant way to do this that has more options.

Thank you

Comment: I am trying to understand the Linq intersect, after reading it seems that if I want to use Intersect I would need a comparer.I'm not that privy to Linq otherwise I would not be here.  I attempted a IEqualityComparer public class SampleComparer2 : IEqualityComparer<Sample>
        {

            public bool Equals(Sample xrSample, Sample islSample)
            {
                return xrSample.StateType != islSample.StateType;
            }

            public int GetHashCode(Sample sample)
            {
                return sample.GetHashCode();
            }
        }

Comment: Does https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/issues/63 help?

Comment: *Intersection* is a term from set theory. In relational algebra the same is called *join*.

Comment: A set Intersect is not the same as a time period intersect, which I think is confusing here, since LINQ has an `Intersect` method. Perhaps if you said _overlapping_ it would be clearer? Also, then you could clarify if overlapping is sufficient or you need _containment_ of one time period by another? And can it happen in either direction?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and help with verbiage.  Yes, I would say overlapping would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you are trying to do what amounts to

```
public static IEnumerable<Sample> MakeSamples(
    IEnumerable<Sample> listOfSamples1,
    IEnumerable<Sample> listOfSamples2) =>
    listOfSamples2.Where(s2 =>
        listOfSamples1.Any(s1 =>
            s1.SampleState != s2.SampleState &&
            s2.EndTime >= s1.StartTime &&
            s2.StartTime <= s1.EndTime));
```

Answer (score 0):

as you mentioned you are trying to understand `linq`

here i have created a `linq` query to do what you want.

```
    List<Sample> intersectSample =
    (from sample in ListOfSamples2
        where
            ListOfSamples1.Any(s => s.StartTime < sample.StartTime &&
                                    s.EndTime > sample.EndTime &&
                                    s.SampleState != sample.SampleState)
        select sample).ToList();
```

It will search for every entry in `List2` (same as `foreach(Sample sample in ListOfSamles2)` ), if in `List1` it find any entry (same as nested `foreach` loop) which satisfy all conditions, it will select that entry (`sample) of`List2` and store it in resultant list.

same thing can be done like below too.

```
List<Sample> intersectSampleLamadaOnly = ListOfSamples2.Where(sample =>
       ListOfSamples1.Any(s => 
             s.StartTime < sample.StartTime && 
             s.EndTime > sample.EndTime && 
             s.SampleState != sample.SampleState)).ToList();
```